# The Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Particles are suspended in a liquid medium at a concentration of 6 particles per ml. A large volume of the suspension is thoroughly agitated, and then 3 ml are withdrawn. What is the probability that exactly 15 particles are withdrawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual model is that the number of particles in a $3$ ml sample has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=(6)(3)$. If $X$ is the number of particles in the sample, the model gives
$$\Pr(X=15)=e^{-18} \frac{(18)^{15}}{15!}.$$